# Verify with xUnit and Moq if a method was executed base on a condition

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit.net

With xUnit and Moq check if a method is executed base on the return value of another method. Example:

```
public class A 
{
    public bool M1() { // return true or false ... }
    public void M2() { // Do something ..... }
}

public class B 
{
    private A objectA;

    public B(A a)
    {
        objectA = a;
    }

    public void Mb ()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            if (objectA.M1())
            {
                return;
            }

            objectA.M2();
       }
    }
}
```

I want to verify something like this:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<A> mockA = new Mock<A>();
    mockA.Setup(x => x.M1()).Return(true);
    mockA.Setup(x => x.M2());

    // Act
    B b = new B(mockA.object);
    b.Mb();

    // Assert
    mockA.Verify(m => m.M2(), """all exactly time that M1 returned false"""); // if this were possible it would be perfect
}
```

Is it possible to do something like that with xUnit and Moq ??

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to check. Your example verifies that M2 was called. You could also verify that M1 was called if you wanted. I'm not sure what else you want it to do?

Comment: I edited the question. I would like to verify if M2 was called exactly the amount of times M1 returns true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<A> mockA = new Mock<A>();
        int count = 0;
        mockA.Setup(x => x.M1()).Returns(true).Callback(() => { count++; });
        mockA.Setup(x => x.M2());

        // Act
        B b = new B(mockA.Object);
        b.Mb();

        // Assert
        mockA.Verify(m => m.M2(), Times.Exactly(count), "all exactly time that M1 returned false");
    }
```